# ARM64 向け Linux Kernel をビルドしたが arch/arm64/boot に Image が生成されない

Tags: linux, build, kernel

下記のリンク先にあるようにqemuで自分でビルドしたカーネルでBusyBoxを動かしてみたくてDockerコンテナ内でLinuxカーネルをクロスビルドしているのですが、ビルドが終了しても`arch/arm64/boot`にkernel imageがありません。
なぜでしょうか?

Dockerコンテナはarchlinux:base-develを使用しています。

ビルドは

```
export ARCH=arm64
export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
```

とした状態で

```
make defconfig
make Image dtbs -j8
```

Linux 6.1.8をビルドしようとしています。

参考リンク先
https://www.honamium.net/post/run_linux_arm64/

---

リンク先の通りに実行してみましたがうまく行きませんでした
Imageは存在しませんでした。

```
$ make ARCH=arm64 defconfig
$ make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- Image dtbs -j`nproc`
```

Comment: 環境変数と引数では同じ優先度ではないので, まずはリンク先にあるとおりに実行してみては？

Comment: Docker を使用しているなら Docker に関する情報も質問中に記載してください。 / まずは make の実行結果をログに残すなどして、正常に実行されているのか辺りから確認すべきかと。

Comment: `defconfig` で, `configuration written to .config` と最後に表示されますか？ (linuxディレクトリの下にそのファイルが生成されてるはず)。一応こちらでは `Image`は作成されます)

Comment: make defconfigのあとにはきちんと表示されています

Comment: 質問にはそのこと記したほうがよいでしょう (`.config`ファイルが存在することも)。どこまで進んだのか判断できます。実際のコンパイルでは何か尋ねてくるはずですがどう応えたのでしょう？デフォルトでしょうか。それらも質問に追加しておくとよいかも

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 短い回答:

- [archlinux:base-devel](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/archlinux/base-devel/images/sha256-e690019ae204ea3d59906824d1a2e91c958c54240002a4749c3f86f9cdb9b643?context=explore) のコンテナイメージだけでは、コンパイルに必要なパッケージがいくつか不足しています。
- 参照している記事は `apt` を使っているので Debian/Ubuntu かと思われますが、「Arm64向けLiuxの準備」の部分をよく読むべきです。
- コマンドの実行結果 (エラーメッセージ) にも重要なヒントとなる情報が含まれています。
  自分自身で確認したり、質問時にも提示すべきです。

---

#### 試した手順:

カーネル ソースコードのダウンロードと、`make ARCH=arm64 defconfig` までは大きな問題はありません。(実際には `git` や `ssh` コマンドも不足しているので、参照している記事そのままのコマンドでのクローンはできませんでした)

以下のコマンドを実行すると、クロスコンパイラの "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc が見つからない" とエラーになります。

```
# make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- Image dtbs -j`nproc`
arch/arm64/Makefile:36: Detected assembler with broken .inst; disassembly will be unreliable 
  SYNC    include/config/auto.conf 
scripts/Kconfig.include:39: C compiler 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' not found 
make[2]: *** [scripts/kconfig/Makefile:77: syncconfig] Error 1 
make[1]: *** [Makefile:708: syncconfig] Error 2 
make: *** [Makefile:809: include/config/auto.conf] Error 2 
make: *** [include/config/auto.conf] Deleting file 'include/generated/rustc_cfg' 
make: *** [include/config/auto.conf] Deleting file 'include/generated/autoconf.h'
```

パッケージを追加インストールします。

```
# pacman -S aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
```

再度 make を実行すると、一見エラーは出ませんが、`ls ./arch/arm64/boot/` で確認すると `dtbs` はあるものの、`Image` は確かに生成されていません。

今度は make 実行時にターゲット指定を "Image" のみにして実行してみると、"bc コマンドが見つからない" とエラーが出ていました。

```
# make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- Image -j`nproc` 
  CC      kernel/bounds.s 
/bin/sh: line 1: bc: command not found 
/bin/sh: line 1: echo: write error: Broken pipe 
  CHKSHA1 include/linux/atomic/atomic-arch-fallback.h 
make[1]: *** [Kbuild:24: include/generated/timeconst.h] Error 127 
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... 
  CHKSHA1 include/linux/atomic/atomic-instrumented.h 
make: *** [Makefile:1298: prepare0] Error 2
```

パッケージを再度追加インストールします。

```
$ pacman -S bc
```

パッケージ追加後に改めて make を実行することで、Image も生成されることを確認しました。

```
# make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- Image -j`nproc`
```